# Consulta personalizada con eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos modelos `Product` e `ImageCat` con una relación de muchos a muchos
y en la tabla pivote guardo tambien el path absoluto de la imágen tal que asi
ejemplo de lo que puede tener la tabla pivote

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
| product_id | imagecat_id |                  filepath                   |
+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
|          1 |        1    | /home/takyo/www/laravel/public/img/img1.jpg |
|          1 |        2    | /home/takyo/www/laravel/public/img/img2.jpg |
|          2 |        1    | /home/takyo/www/laravel/public/img/img3.jpg |
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

para acceder a la ruta de la imagen y ponerselo al src de una etiqueta `<img>` no me vale hacer directamente acceder al filepath
`{{ $product->images->find(1)->pivot->filepath }}`

Lo que no se es si con eloquent se puede acceder directamente a un parser que yo haya programado en algun lado para que yo pueda hacer esto tal que asi.

Nota: src es el parser de filepath
`{{ $product->images->find(1)->src }}`
o asi
`{{ $product->images->find(1)->pivot->src }}`

ya se que la solución rapida es crear otro atributo src o que la ruta sea directamente la pública del servidor. Esta pregunta es por una duda en mi aprendizaje.

Otro ejemplo que se me ocurre podría ser
`$user->nombre_completo` donde el atributo nombre_completo no está en la bd y es la unión de los campos nombre y apellido

Comment: para que necesitas el parser? es porque guardaste el path absoluto en vez de un path relativo al proyecto?

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ En este ejemplo si, haria falta un parser, aunque lo he solucionado como ya he comentado poniendo la ruta relativa. Me pregunto como se haria un campo calculado no existente en la bd desde eloquent. He actualizado con otro pequeño ejemplo.

Comment: Ok, creo que te refieres a un accesssor. No puedo escribir una respuesta ahora, pero en la documentación está el ejemplo de nombre completo https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor. Dale una mirada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) para devolver valores nuevos calculados de atributos existentes en un modelo:

```php
/**
 * Obtener el nombre completo.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNombreCompletoAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->nombre} {$this->apellido}";
}
```

Como puedes ver, el valor que devolverá esta función, será la concatenación de los atributos `nombre` y `apellido`, que sí tienen una columna correspondiente en BD. Luego, para acceder al valor del Accessor, puedes acceder al atributo `nombre_completo` en una instancia de modelo:

```php
$modelo = Modelo::find(1);

$nombreCompleto = $modelo->nombre_completo;
```

Esto te servirá mientras estés trabajando directamente sobre una instancia de Eloquent\Model. Si además quieres que estos valores calculados se agreguen a las representaciones de matriz/JSON de tu modelo, deberás anexarlos.

[Anexar valores a matriz/JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) de un modelo
Ocasionalmente, al convertir modelos a una matriz o JSON, es posible que desees agregar atributos que no tienen una columna correspondiente en su base de datos.
Después de crear el accessor (sigo con el ejemplo de nombre completo), agrega el nombre del atributo a la propiedad `appends` en el modelo. Ten en cuenta que los nombres de los atributos se mencionan normalmente en "snake_case", aunque el accessor se define usando "camelCase":

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Modelo extends Model
{
    /**
     * Los accessors para anexar al modelo en forma de matriz.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['nombre_completo'];
    /**
    * Obtener el nombre completo.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getNombreCompletoAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->nombre} {$this->apellido}";
    }
}
```

Una vez que el atributo se ha agregado a la lista de anexos, se incluirá tanto en la matriz del modelo como en las representaciones JSON.

```php
$modelo = App\Modelo::first();

$array = $modelo->toArray();

$json = $modelo->toJson();

$pretty_json = $modelo->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Alternativamente, puedes convertir un modelo o colección en un `string`, que llamará automáticamente al método `toJson` en el modelo o colección:

```php
$string = (string) $modelo;
```

Dado que los modelos y las colecciones se convierten a JSON cuando se convierten en un string, si devuelves objetos Eloquent directamente desde las rutas o controladores de tu aplicación, éstos también contendrán los atributos anexados:

```php
Route::get('modelos', function () {
    return App\Modelo::all();
});
```